# Firebase firestore not letting me set variable as document path in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, calendar

I am currently trying to make an app that displays quotes daily, my problem is that I need to set my firestore document path to a date. When I type in a date it works but when I set a variable that is the date that I get from the calendar function, it does not work?

This is when it works

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-DD-YYYY");
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("2021").document("1-25-2021");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String quote = document.getString("Quote");
                    String wikiPage = document.getString("Wiki");
                    quoteView.setText(quote);
                    wikiView.loadUrl(wikiPage);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is when it Doesn't

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-DD-YYYY");
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
  
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("2021").document(dateTime);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String quote = document.getString("Quote");
                    String wikiPage = document.getString("Wiki");
                    quoteView.setText(quote);
                    wikiView.loadUrl(wikiPage);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks in Advance for any help!!!

Comment: Are you able to post the exact exception you're getting (if any)? Also if you could post the actual value of `dateTime` in the second example it would be helpful.

Comment: the date and time is supposed to be today's date so it would be 1-26-2021 and in firestore I have set up a collection called "2021", a document that is called "1-26-2021", and 2 fields called "Quote" and "Wiki"

Comment: I want the calendar does get the date but the document path in firestore only seems to except text in quotations and not variables?

Comment: So in both of your examples, you are passing a string. In the second one (the broken version), you are passing it `String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());`, this is a string.

Comment: If you wanted to pass it a date object, you would omit the line in my last comment and just do  `.document(calendar.getTime());` (although this isn't really what you want, you should be using string values).

Comment: The firestore function is not pulling any data so there is no null or any text.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that is what I need but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I believe both of your examples are almost identical. The first example, you are typing a string `1-25-2021`. In the second example, you are creating a string using a date formatter. Since the date formatter is using format `MM-DD-YYYY`, I believe the string would be `01-25-2021`. I would suggest in your first example, change `1-25-2021` to `01-25-2021` and see if it gives you the same problem.

Comment: I worked!, Thank you so much, Greg! This was my first app and it was my main problem, thank you again!!!

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, how do you mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: I just posted the answer separately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both of your examples are almost identical. The first example, you are typing a string `1-25-2021`. In the second example, you are creating a string using a date formatter. Since the date formatter is using format `MM-DD-YYYY`, I believe the string would be `01-25-2021`. I would suggest in your first example, change `1-25-2021` to `01-25-2021` and see if it gives you the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

> I believe both of your examples are almost identical. The first example, you are typing a string 1-25-2021. In the second example, you are creating a string using a date formatter. Since the date formatter is using format MM-DD-YYYY, I believe the string would be 01-25-2021. I would suggest in your first example, change 1-25-2021 to 01-25-2021 and see if it gives you the same problem. – Greg, this is the correct anwser